# Git pull to a non remote branch

Tags: git, git-pull

I've a  branch which I don't want to have as a remote branch since I'm only using it for testing purposes. Now when I try to pull(fetch and merge) from my remote master branch to my  branch, I get the error:

```
fatal: No remote for the current branch.
```

How can I merge my remote master branch with my non remote  branch

Edit: I don't want to merge into and change the local master branch. I want to directly merge the remote master into local testing branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the location of your merge branch like this:

```
git merge origin/master
```

That will merge the master branch from origin into your local branch.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are currently in your local branch, which you don't want to commit.

```
 $ git commit -am "Commit message"
 $ git checkout master
 $ git pull origin master
 $ git checkout branch_name
 $ git merge master
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly

You have to git pull on to your master branch and then in your non-master branch, "git rebase master"

You need to pull from your master branch to your other branch.

Comment: I recall reading some articles that you shouldn't use rebase whenever merge is an option.  I forget the exact reasons though.